# Loop over a large number of CSV files with the same statements in R?

Tags: r, list, loops, csv

I'm having a lot of trouble reading/writing to CSV files. Say I have over 300 CSV's in a folder, each being a matrix of values.

If I wanted to find out a characteristic of each individual CSV file such as which rows had an exact number of 3's, and write the result to another CSV fil for each test, how would I go about iterating this over 300 different CSV files?

For example, say I have this code I am running for each file:

```
values_4 <- read.csv(file = 'values_04.csv', header=FALSE)  // read CSV in as it's own DF
values_4$howMany3s <- apply(values_04, 1, function(x) length(which(x==3))) // compute number of 3's 
values_4$exactly4 <- apply(values_04[50], 1, function(x) length(which(x==4))) // show 1/0 on each column that has exactly four 3's 
values_4 // print new matrix
```

I am then continuously copy and pasting this code and changing the "4" to a 5, 6, etc and noting the values. This seems wildly inefficient to me but I'm not experienced enough at R to know exactly what my options are. Should I look at adding all 300 CSV files to a single list and somehow looping through them?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you can read all the files and proceess them.  Untested code as you haven't given us anything to work on.

```
# Get a list of CSV files. Use the path argument to point to a folder
# other than the current working directory
files <- list.files(pattern=".+\\.csv")

# For each file, work your magic
# lapply runs the function defined in the second argument on each
# value of the first argument
everything <- lapply(
  files,
  function(f) {
    values <- read.csv(f, header=FALSE)
    apply(values, 1, function(x) length(which(x==3)))
  }
)
# And returns the results in a list.  Each element consists of 
# the results from one function call.
# Make sure you can access the elements of the list by filename
names(everything) <- files

# The return value is a list.  Access all of it with
everything

# Or a single element with
everything[["values04.csv"]]
```